# Call serverless functions in offline mode of MongoDB Realm Sync

Tags: react-native, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm

MongoDB Realm allows the creation of [serverless functions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/functions/) on the cloud which can be called from the client SDK.

My query is when working with Realm sync, are these functions also synced to the local database and can they be called on the locally synced database in **offline mode**. If yes what would be the correct way of doing it with react-native assuming that the basic configurations have been done for connection? If not then do I need to rewrite the complex function logic(which does more than just querying and filtering) on the client-side?

I did some basic investigation but could not find any concrete answers except [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-realm-offline-with-graphql-and-functions/117765). This answer assumes that the functions are called using [HTTPS endpoints](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/endpoints/) but my intention is to call these functions directly on the client without endpoints.

Comment: Do you have got any solution for this?